# Hide breadcrumb items when longer than container

Tags: wpf, xaml, modern-ui

I've created a breadcrumb in my XAML using a `ListBox` control. It works nicely. However, when I try to show add too many items, naturally it only shows some of them. I want to somehow hide the left-hand items until the right element is visible. Ideally it should leave some free space (on right) too. How can I do this?

```
                <ListBox Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="breadcrumb"
            MinWidth="300" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="8,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#111"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAA"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-8,0,0,0">
                                            <Image Source="Assets/breadcrumb.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="35" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to build a custom `Panel` for the `ListBox.ItemsPanelTemplate`. Your required functionality could be created quite simply in this manner as you will essentially be able to measure each breadcrumb as it is rendered and only show the ones that fit.

If you have no experience of this yet, don't be put off... you can achieve some wonderful things with custom `Panel`s. Here are some articles to help you if you need them:

[Panels Overview (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements),

[How to create a Custom Layout Panel in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html)

[Creating Custom Panels In WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF)

Comment: Huh! I didn't know it would require this much efford :D I thought there's some property that could align items on the right... I have no experience in this. Let me explore this and get back to you. In the meantime if possible, please elaborate a little more of what you think I should do once I created the panel.

Comment: Creating a custom `Panel` is not that difficult... you only have to implement two methods. However, there are many ways to achieve the effect that you are after. I just recommended the custom `Panel` route because that's how I would do it and because it fits with the method that you have chosen so far. Alternatively, you can just try replacing the `StackPanel` in your `ItemsPanelTemplate` with a `WrapPanel` and experimenting with the various alignment options the `Panel/ListBox` provide.